# NPM throws error?

Tags: npm

I'm using node 0.10.31 and PHP 5.4.30. I get an error when I use the command `npm i`:

```
yiff$ npm i

> pro@0.1.0 install /Users/yiff/Documents/WebstormProjects/test/
> cake setup

Possibly unhandled Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
From previous event:
at Object._.extend.spawn     (/Users/yiff/Documents/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/nobone/node_modules/nokit/dist/kit.js:1234:15)
at /Users/yiff/Documents/WebstormProjects/yiff/Cakefile:32:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
npm WARN unmet dependency 
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: "Yes". Please write a useful/focused title.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with PHP? Seems entirely unrelated. Removing the tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm` is trying to do the install but failing because a needed command is missing.  I don't know which command -- it could be `git`, it could be the C++ compiler `g++`.

The easiest way to find out what command it's trying to execute is to update your npm.  Since it looks like you're on a unix-like machine, the command you want is

`npm install -g npm@latest`

If that fails due to EACCES, try doing it as root:

`sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

If neither of those work, try following the troubleshooting instructions from the npm wiki: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm or post back here and I will help you.

Once you have an up-to-date `npm`, you can rerun the `npm i` command in your project directory and `npm` should tell you which program it's trying to execute but not finding; post that here and we can go on from there.